# Access file descriptor from FILE * pointer in C

Tags: c, linux

Is it possible to access file descriptor from file pointer in c ?
If not then why ? 
I tried using `fp->fd` but i am getting compilation error:

```
File has no member named fd
```

what shall i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Linux and other Unices, there is a function `fileno` in `<stdio.h>` which should give you that information.  Just be sure that you're compiling with the flags necessary to see this function.